# Correct Oracle client for .Net

Tags: oracle, client, updates

Our application is developped with .Net Framework 4, C#.

After seeing that kind of problem : 
[ORA-12571: TNS:packet writer failure with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151175/ora-12571-tnspacket-writer-failure-with-asp-net)

I chose to update my Oracle client to version 11.2.0.3.

In order to make our DatabaseProvider work, we're using those dlls :

**file_name (version)**

- oci.dll (11.2.0.1)
- ociw32.dll (11.1.0.1)
- Oracle.DataAccess.dll (4.112.0.2)
- orannzsbb11.dll (11.0.0.1)
- oraocci11.dll (11.2.0.2)
- oraociei11.dll (11.2.0.1)
- OraOps11w.dll (2.112.2.0)
- orasql11.dll (11.1.0.6)

My question is : my client is running on Windows Server 2008 R2 :

I've found this but i'm not sure that are libraries are corrects :

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/winx64soft-089540.html

After unzipping "instantclient-basic-windows.x64-11.2.0.3.0" I can't find those two dlls :

- Oracle.DataAccess
- OraOps11w

Being a total beginner to Oracle databases, am I following the right path or not ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link you provided: *Instant Client Package - Basic: All files required to run OCI, OCCI, and JDBC-OCI applications* gives you the instant client to be used for JAVA applications.

For .NET you need ODP.NET: 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-101290.html

and the 64bit version: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/windows/downloads/index-090165.html

I recommend you use the XCopy version (even if you are beginner). The included readme.htm in the zip file provides all the necessary instructions.

Comment: Does it mean that I need only two dlls, that are : Oracle.DataAccess
and OraOps11w ? If I'm using the install.bat script, does it it keep me from having to copy paste my dlls in my application folder ? It updates the PATH accordingly to my oracle client install ?

Comment: You don't need to add those DLLs to your application folder if you used the install.bat (because Oracle.DataAccess should be placed in the GAC by install.bat). But if you want a minimal setup take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923283/what-is-the-minimal-setup-required-to-deploy-a-net-application-with-oracle-clie